# changing a tag href depends on window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create a jQuery snippet which detect the ***window's url*** and depends on the ***window's href***, change the ***a tag***'s href.

My code is so far:

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      var changeLink = document.getElementById("LinkTag");
      console.log('it is running');
      if ($(window).location.href() == "pageUrl") {
        changeLink.href = "website1";
      } else {
        changeLink.href = "website2";
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks

Comment: What jquery has to do with window and beef?

Comment: @Shilly and `.location` is a `window` property, not a `$()` property :)

Comment: there is no location property in jQuery and href is NOT a method so I am sure there error in your console states that. Learn to debug with your console.

Comment: @Alex. My comment was that it's a property. I never stated that it was connected to jquery.

Comment: @epascarello believe or not, the console did not give me an error! But thanks for your really nice comment. People are here to help each other, right?

Comment: @Regina I created a test page: https://jsfiddle.net/b4v0mowd/1/ and I see the error in my console `Cannot read property 'href' of undefined` so I am not sure what would be different in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of things going on here:

1. `location.href` is not a jQuery method; it's a property of the regular window object.  Use `window.location.href` instead of `$(window).location.href()`.
2. It looks like you're trying to match the string "pageUrl" instead of a variable -- unless that was intended as a sample string in the question, the variable name shouldn't be enclosed in quotes.
3. You probably don't want to match against the full `window.location.href`, which includes things (such as the protocol, subdomains, hash, and URL parameters) that can vary while still pointing to the same page; `window.location.pathname` is usually a safer bet (assuming you're trying to match a specific page.)
4. It's not necessary to wrap your script in an IIFE and a `document.ready` and a `window.onload`.  I've removed the redundant layers here.
5. (Optional)  Mixing jQuery methods and vanilla methods can be confusing to maintain, because you have to keep track of which variables contain jQuery objects and which contain references to regular DOM nodes. Since you've already got jQuery elsewhere, I swapped out your `document.getElementById` for its jQuery equivalent here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pageUrl = "/js"; // This is the path when running in a stackoverflow snippet
  var changeLink = $("#LinkTag");
  if (window.location.pathname == pageUrl) {
    changeLink.attr("href","//example.com");
  } else {
    changeLink.attr("href","//somethingelse.com");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="LinkTag">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your comment. I did remove the window.onload, changed the window.location.href and working perfectly. :)

Answer (score -1):

Repalce your `$(window).location`  for just `window.location`

```
if (window.location.href == "pageUrl")
          changeLink.href = "website1";
     else 
        changeLink.href = "website2";
```